# Docker security issue

Tags: docker

On a single VM I have two users user1 and user2.

If as user1 I run : `docker run myimage`
and map my readonly file to a file in the container, I get a new container running.

My file has 400 permissions, so on the host it is only I who sees the file. Also the file has 400 permissions inside the container.

If user attaches to the container using `docker exec -it bash`, he is able to see the mapped file.

This means the file that was protected carefully by user1 is exposed to user2.

Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: If a user is running docker commands, they have pseudo `root` access to the VM so whatever you do is not actually going to protect the file.

Comment: What is the solution? My protected file needs to be available in the container started by me. I want to prevent anyone else from connecting to the container.

Comment: Don't give the other user access to docker.

Comment: Instead is there a way the docker container started by me becomes accessible only to me? Alternatively, is it possible to force users to provide a -u <username> switch so that they can access the container only as their own user? This will ensure my protected file will not be exposed to them.

Comment: The container is started by root. The command may be sent by you but everything docker does is done as the root user. Docker has no fine grained security in the daemon.   Again, you have to restrict the other users access to docker.  Once you've done that you could allow a sudo script for a specific docker command or a program that talks to the API that can only allows specific calls.

Comment: How do I prevent other users from accessing docker? Even non-root users are currently able to access docker.